# SQL server : clearing cache has no effect on IO stats

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

Query used:

(had copied the cache cleanup code from somewhere online)

```
CHECKPOINT; 
GO 
DBCC DROPCLEANBUFFERS; 
GO
DBCC DROPCLEANBUFFERS
GO

SET STATISTICS TIME ON;
SET STATISTICS IO ON;

select a.a,a.b from t1 a JOIN t1 b on a.i=b.i
```

t1 's schema is

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[t1](
    [i] [int] NULL,
    [a] [varchar](1000) NULL,
    [b] [varchar](1000) NULL,
    [c] [varchar](1000) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

And t1 is populated with random data (`I` ranges from 0-11 and a,b,c are populated with `NEWID()` values)

It contains about 900 rows (934 to be exact)

The results of executing the query are:

> SQL Server parse and compile time:     CPU time = 0 ms, elapsed time =
>   0 ms.
>
> SQL Server Execution Times:    CPU time = 0 ms,  elapsed time = 55
>   ms. SQL Server parse and compile time:     CPU time = 0 ms, elapsed
>   time = 0 ms. DBCC execution completed. If DBCC printed error messages,
>   contact your system administrator.
>
> SQL Server Execution Times:    CPU time = 0 ms,  elapsed time = 4 ms.
>   SQL Server parse and compile time:     CPU time = 0 ms, elapsed time =
>   0 ms. DBCC execution completed. If DBCC printed error messages,
>   contact your system administrator.
>
> SQL Server Execution Times:    CPU time = 0 ms,  elapsed time = 1 ms.
>   SQL Server parse and compile time:     CPU time = 0 ms, elapsed time =
>   0 ms.
>
> SQL Server Execution Times:    CPU time = 0 ms,  elapsed time = 0 ms.
>
> SQL Server Execution Times:    CPU time = 0 ms,  elapsed time = 0 ms.
>
> (115974 row(s) affected) Table 'Worktable'. Scan count 0, logical
>   reads 0, **physical reads 0**, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0,
>   lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0. Table 't1'. Scan count
>   2, logical reads 32, **physical reads 0**, read-ahead reads 20, lob
>   logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
>
> SQL Server Execution Times:    CPU time = 79 ms,  elapsed time =
>   15858 ms.

As I understand it, a clean cache should result in a significant number of physical reads, shouldn't it?

(SQL server 2012 running on a Win 8 guest VM running on Hyper V on a Win 8 host)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The item you have highlighted is for a `Worktable` (e.g. spool) created in `tempdb` during the course of the query. Not a pre-existing table that needs to be read in from disc.

The line for `t1` should show some physical reads and or read-ahead reads.

(Edit: Didn't see that was included originally). The below shows 20 read-ahead reads from `t1`

```
Table 't1'. Scan count 2, logical reads 32, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 20
```

This means all pages were brought into cache by the read ahead mechanism.

Comment: Fixed the formatting..  So, a read ahead read is also a physical read?

Comment: Yes. SQL Server can bring pages in from disc in advance of them actually being needed via a separate read ahead thread.  trace flag 652 can be used (on a development instance) to temporarily turn off read ahead. If you try `DBCC TRACEOFF (652)` you should see no read ahead reads and all physical.

Comment: @Akash - The above comment should have said `DBCC TRACEON (652)` of course to turn the trace flag on.

Comment: Though apparently it needs to be DBCC TRACEON (652,-1) in my case